# Huge difference of sample size

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

I have two samples, one has 34 measurements the other one has over 10000, neither of them follow normal distribution. Are there any pitfalls directly comparing two samples with huge different sizes? I am thinking of using the Mann-Whitney test. 
Should I first do downsampling first? to equal the sample size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two samples of such different sizes, when one sample is large, is actually quite similar to doing a one-sample comparison to a known distribution.  To see this, imagine the more extreme case where you are comparing a sample of size $34$ to a sample of size $\infty$.  In the latter case, the infinite sample is equivalent to knowledge of the superpopulation, so you effectively have a one-sample test.

In the present case, the sample with $10,000$ values is going to tend to give you a highly accurate estimate of the underlying population distribution, and so having this sample is somewhat "close to" having knowledge of the population.  Most of the uncertainty in this comparison is going to come from the first population, where you only have a small sample size.  There are no inherent pitfalls in comparing samples of such different sizes, but obviously it would be desirable if you could get more data from the first population.

Comment: Thank you so much