# What test should I be using?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I'm trying to compare differences between site conditions in areas that experienced tree death for the first time between two years. I have a dataset of presence/absence of mortality at the SAME sites in 2011 and 2015. From that dataset, I would like to extract sites in both 2011 and 2015 that saw tree mortality for the first time and compare differences in environmental variables (i.e elevation, slope, aspect). This results in unequal sample sizes (more sites saw mortality in 2011 [91 sites] than 2015 [51 sites]) and I believe the data is also dependent (the same sites were sampled in 2011 and 2015- although the data isn't paired, the same site could not show up in both 2011 and 2015). Here is example dataset:

[image: Example Dataset]

I'm quite confused as to which test I should run to compare the differences between the two years. Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Welch's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test). This test allows for two independent samples with unequal variances and sample sizes. This test however is not as reliable for smaller sample sizes.

Comment: Thank you. But what if the samples aren't independent? For example, you wouldn't see a sample site that occurred in 2011 in 2015, so I believe my dataset is lacking independence.

Comment: Ahh I see. You might try to look at the approach discussed in this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90644/how-to-compare-two-non-normally-distributed-samples-with-very-different-sizes?rq=1).

Comment: Hmm but the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney has an assumption of independent data. Still unsure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Non-parametric tests do not make assumptions about the underlying distribution. You may need to look to this group for your analysis. The [two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/ks2samp.htm)  is an option.

Comment: After further thought, you are working with unbalanced panel data. Two time periods with unequal observations in each. This will be another consideration in your analysis.

Comment: I was just reading in a statistics textbook and found that you could use a Student's t two sample test for two **dependent** samples if they are randomly selected. So you do a random selection of paired samples. Would that work for what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply-- that sounds about right-- might you cite the statistics textbook? Thank you.

Comment: The [textbook](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/product/Triola-Elementary-Statistics-12th-Edition/9780321836960.html) is Mario Triola's Elementary statistics Section 9.4 Two Dependent Samples (Matched Pairs). Not sure if your data is not paired. The assumptions don't require equal samples sizes from what I can tell. Best of luck!